# Merge into и сложное условие

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper, sql-merge

Написал код который обновляет цены в таблице

```
MERGE INTO OBSOLETE_PRICE p1
USING ACTUAL_PRICE a1
  ON (p1.ID = a1.ID) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN  UPDATE SET p1.price = a1.price;
```

Вопрос - как обновить только 1 строку? Например где `p1.ID = 5`. Пробовал `AND` писать после `(p1.ID = a1.ID)` и после `WHEN MATCHED` везде ругается. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прошу прощения, я с дуру делал вам пример для ms server.

Comment: Добавте в `update` условие `where p1.ID = 5`.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Так поменяйте там на oracle.

Comment: @0xdb, уже сделано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны добавить условие в самом операторе `WHEN MATCHED`([пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/089a3/6))

```
MERGE INTO OBSOLETE_PRICE p1
USING ACTUAL_PRICE a1
ON (p1.ID = a1.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET p1.price = a1.price
   WHERE p1.ID = 2
```

Comment: На And ругается - Syntax error, требует THEN поставить

Comment: @dimababin, внес правку.